# Búsqueda de registros en un rango de horas en un log

Tags: linux, awk

Tengo un log de "errores.log" con la siguiente estructura.

```
01/24/2024 08:18:49 Schedule will be refreshed in 1 hour.
01/24/2024 09:18:50 Session established with server01:
01/24/2024 09:18:51 Session established with server02:
01/24/2024 09:18:52 Session established with server03:
01/24/2024 09:18:53 Session established with server01:
01/24/2024 09:18:54 failed with 420: ERROR_SOCKET_CLOSED
01/24/2024 09:19:01 Objects:
01/24/2024 09:19:02 Options:
01/24/2024 09:19:03 failed with 420: GSK_ERROR_SOCKET_CLOSED
01/24/2024 09:19:51 Session established with server05:
01/24/2024 09:19:52 Session established with server06:
01/24/2024 09:19:53 Session established with server07:
```

Estoy intentando usar awk de la siguiente forma:

```
awk \
-v end_date=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")\
-v begin_date=$(date --date "30 min ago" +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")\
'
/ERROR/ && $1 >= begin_date && $1 <= end_date {print}
'\
< "/clientes/logs/errores.log"
```

Me esta enviando un mensaje de error de sintaxis

GRACIAS, por la orientación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy tratando de extraer del log, los últimos mensajes de error que se han registrado los últimos 30 minutos. Por ello obtengo la fecha y hora actual y 30 minutos antes. Los paso como parámetros.

Comment: Por las dudas lo comento, una solución no exacta pero seguramente más performante , es usar `tail` y quedarse con los últimos n registros. El problema de filtrar por hora es que tienes que leer e interpretar el archivo completo.

Comment: Gracias. Podría hacer un tail -f y enviar la salida usando |tee  pero realmente lo que intento es que este proceso después corra en un cron y envié un correo electrónico si hay mensajes de error.

Comment: Así como en la primer línea tienes un espacio antes de `\\`, te falta ese espacio en el resto de las líneas.

Comment: Te complica el espacio en la fecha, de tal manera que no se definen correctamente las variables de fecha. Suena que es mas fácil que exportes las fechas con formato y las asignes entrecomilladas: `-v end_date="$END_DATE"`.